# Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list in Union

Tags: mysql, fulltext-index

I keep getting this error:

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

I already added ADD FULLTEXT function.

this is my code:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(text1, content) AGAINST('$name') AS score FROM subcont WHERE MATCH(text1, content) AGAINST('$name') ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE for the table.